# how to Automate the SQL Server 2008 Database and OLAP backup?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, powershell

I have SQL Server 2008 Enterprise SP2 x64 database in my Windows Server 2008 Enterprise, my question is how to perform automated backup for both database content ? eg. the MDF and the LDF as well as the OLAP database ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open SQL Server Management Studio 2008 and connect to your database server.
Expand Management > Maintenance Plans > right click Backups > New Maintenance Plan... > double click Back Up Database Task > double click the new task in the right hand pane and enter your settings for the backup here.
You can enter the databases and destination file/s here. I'm sure you can figure out the schedule settings and stuff. Try googling "sql server management studio backup task"

Comment: ay yes, that'd be great with wizard.

Answer (score 1):

Create a SQL maintenance plan that backs up the databases on a schedule.

Comment: Glad to help, AW.